# Bokeh.Plotting unable to plot circles or circle markers for unordered data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, bokeh

Am very new to Bokeh and I am trying to refer to the below URL for plotting circles for my data points in a dataframe.

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/markers/circle.html

I changed the x,y and sizes variables to the below, however my plot comes out to be blank.

```
x = np.array([df['R']])
y = np.array([df['B']])
sizes = np.array([df['logabsLCRabs']])
```

Can you please let me know what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
x = df['R'].values
y = df['B'].values
sizes = df['logabsLCRabs'].values
```

Comment: @ HYRY
Could you advise how would i go about if one of my axis has categorical values...
Would i still use .values ?

Comment: @asimo, you can use `df["cat"].tolist()` for categorical columns.